# Getting a string from a range of possible paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a scenario where I need to grab the first occurrence of a string from an object, but only if the match occurs in one of the path's that have been pre-defined.

```
{ id: 'I60ODI', description: 'some random description' }
{ foo: 'bar', description: { color: 'green', text: 'some description within text' } }
```

When provided either of the two objects above, I would expect the solution to return either `some random description` or `some description within text`, provided that the two possible paths are `obj.description` and `obj.description.text`. New paths might also need to be added in the future, so it needs to be easy to add them.

Here is the solution I have implemented so far, but to me it doesn't seem optimal.

```
// require the ramda library
const R = require('ramda');

// is the provided value a string?
const isString = R.ifElse(R.compose(R.equals('string'), (val) => typeof val), R.identity, R.always(false));
const addStringCheck = t => R.compose(isString, t);

// the possible paths to take (subject to scale)
const possiblePaths = [
    R.path(['description']),
    R.path(['description', 'text'])
];
// add the string check to each of the potential paths
const mappedPaths = R.map((x) => addStringCheck(x), possiblePaths);

// select the first occurrence of a string 
const extractString = R.either(...mappedPaths);

// two test objects
const firstObject = { description: 'some random description' };
const secondObject = { description: { text: 'some description within text' } };
const thirdObject = { foo: 'bar' };

console.log(extractString(firstObject)); // 'some random description'
console.log(extractString(secondObject)); // 'some description within text'
console.log(extractString(thirdObject)); // false
```

I would really appreciate it if a seasoned functional programmer might provide me with some alternative approaches to implementation. Thanks.

Comment: Since you have working code, and are really asking for a review, this question is more suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I removed my answer due to your updates.  But I agree with the above comment.  You have working code using the framework you want to use.  Sounds like code review.

Comment: Yep I agree with you guys. Thank you for your time and comments. [The question has been moved](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/177392/150458)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, and I think it's cleaner:

```
const extract = curry((defaultVal, paths, obj) => pipe( 
  find(pipe(path(__, obj), is(String))),
  ifElse(is(Array), path(__, obj), always(defaultVal))
)(paths))

const paths = [['description'], ['description', 'text']]

extract(false, paths, firstObject)  //=> "some random description"
extract(false, paths, secondObject) //=> "some description within text"
extract(false, paths, thirdObject)  //=> false
```

I personally would find a better default in `''` than in `false`, but that's your call.

This avoids mapping over all the paths, stopping when the first one is found.  It also uses Ramda's `is` to replace your complex `isString` with `R.is(String)`.  And the currying lets you supply the first or the first two parameters to create a more useful function.

You can see this in action in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20firstObject%20%3D%20%7B%20description%3A%20%27some%20random%20description%27%20%7D%3B%0Aconst%20secondObject%20%3D%20%7B%20description%3A%20%7B%20text%3A%20%27some%20description%20within%20text%27%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0Aconst%20thirdObject%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%27bar%27%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20extract%20%3D%20curry%28%28defaultVal%2C%20paths%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20pipe%28%20%0A%20%20find%28pipe%28path%28__%2C%20obj%29%2C%20is%28String%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20ifElse%28is%28Array%29%2C%20path%28__%2C%20obj%29%2C%20always%28defaultVal%29%29%0A%29%28paths%29%29%0A%0A%0Aconst%20paths%20%3D%20%5B%5B%27description%27%5D%2C%20%5B%27description%27%2C%20%27text%27%5D%5D%0A%0Aextract%28false%2C%20paths%2C%20firstObject%29%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%22some%20random%20description%22%0Aextract%28false%2C%20paths%2C%20secondObject%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%22some%20description%20within%20text%22%0Aextract%28false%2C%20paths%2C%20thirdObject%29%20%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20false)**.